# Akka stream supervision with TimerGraphStageLogic

Tags: java, error-handling, akka-stream

I've created a materializer for akka streams using a custom supervision strategy:

```
        .withSupervisionStrategy(
            (Function<Throwable, Supervision.Directive>)
                e -> {
                  LOG.error("Unhandled exception in stream", e);
                  return Supervision.stop();
                });
```

I have a `GraphStage` which uses `TimerGraphStageLogic`. Sometimes it throws an exception from the `onTimer` function, but this exception doesn't get propagated to my supervisor. Is that the expected behavior?